# Убрать actionBar и toolbal

Tags: android

Как сделать верхнюю часть активити как на этом рисунке. Т.е. сделать прозрачными или убрать toolbar и actionbar:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в `Activity` следующую строку:

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Для прозрачности statusbar'a добавьте в представление следующую строку:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Или же, например, если API < 21, можно решить проблему добавлением в представление следующих строк:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: А как сделать прозрачным строку состояния? И мне бы хотелось чтобы как на картинке было. цветом или градиентом чтобы заполнялось место где есть тулбар и строка состояния